# Sandbox policy error in a non-sandboxed app

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm using ad hoc (outside App Store) distribution for my document-based app. The app is **NOT** sandboxed, and entitlements are set correctly:

```xml
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <false/>
```

When running the notarized app, it's caught in Gatekeeper. The following kernel error prints in Console over and over again:
`Sandbox: App(33811) System Policy: deny(1) file-write-unlink /Users/user/Library/Autosave Information/xx.name.AppName.plist`

The app doesn't use macOS autosaving (save in place) stuff, but if I'm correct, this `Autosave Information` folder is used for recovering app sessions. I am using `+(BOOL)autosavesDrafts` while `+(BOOL)autosavesInPlace` returns `NO`. I've also overridden `- (NSURL *)autosavedContentsFileURL` to point to the App Support folder, and the URL is served correctly.

When allowed to do so, the app is constantly writing files into the `Autosave Information` folder.

Why and how is the app trying to access this folder all the time, and why is it violating sandbox policy, even when not inside a sandbox?

**EDIT**:

I finally managed to get the real error out of the console. It appears that the app is somehow returning a wrong path for where to save the restoration data. I've tried to find a method which is used to set it, but for now, to no luck.

```
-[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfFile:options:maxLength:error:] + 111
+[NSArray(NSArray) newWithContentsOf:immutable:] + 112
-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenRecordsBeingReopened] + 83
-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:] + 705
-[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:completionHandler:] + 249
```

Comment: Is it a document based app?

Comment: Yes, good point, I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: Do you use other entitlements like user read/write? Which Version of macOS do you use?

Comment: I'm on 10.15.4. I have security entitlements for `files.user-selected.read-write`,`network.client` and `print`.

Comment: So just to make sure. You have a document subclass and not overwritten +(BOOL)autosavesinplace returning YES?

Comment: I've overwritten it to return `NO`, but `+(BOOL)autosavesDrafts` returns `YES`. I tried changing it to false, but it doesn't make any difference regarding the errors.

Comment: Can you Show your nsdocument subclass with only class methods +(...)....

Comment: Those are the only class methods implemented, `+(BOOL)autosavesInPlace` (no)  and `+(BOOL)autosavesDrafts` (yes)

Comment: Please try to remove your entitlements file completely if you are not using sandbox feature. If that solves it I will explain it

Comment: I already tried that (with no idea why I did it), but no luck. `NSDocumentController` keeps on trying to write the recovery files into that path, and has no read/write permissions whatsoever. It doesn't crash the app, and actually seems to manage to write them, too, probably because I'm running in XCode. Otherwise Gatekeeper stops the app from running.

Comment: AHH. I think I get it. The problem is that I've migrated to sandboxed version for another build of the app, and at some point they have shared the same bundle identifier. I don't know how to fix the problem yet, but at least I figured out the reason.

Comment: I added an answer to help anyone else stumbling into a similar issue, when navigating between sandboxed and non-sandboxed versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was some remnants of old a bundle identifier. I had migrated to a sandboxed distribution of the app, and at some point in the process, I had built the sandboxed version with the same bundle identifier. macOS had registered the bundle identifier to belong to a sandboxed app and, probably due to security reasons, no longer wanted to allow it to run non-sandboxed.

I created a fresh `Info.plist`, and changed the bundle identifier and the errors were gone.